# Python Concatenating Bytes Problems (2)

Tags: python, string, error-handling, concatenation, byte

So I am currently pulling information from a list to put into a bight array

for example:

> street number 2894 ----> 2894 is built for a byte string b'\x28\x94

for some reason I am having a major problem trying to concatenate the b'\x' + 28 and 94 I tried:

```
RF_Pack = RF_Pack + b'\x' + Street_Num[i]
```

but got the error

```
PS C:\Users\kkelly\Desktop\AIM\b-AIM-1436> python reset_keys_proflex_08.12.2020_without_print.py ERM com12 proflex_config_file.txt
  File "reset_keys_proflex_08.12.2020_without_print.py", line 338
    RF_Pack = RF_Pack + b'\x' + PanArray[i]
                        ^
SyntaxError: (value error) invalid \x escape at position 0
```

it may be that what I am doing is illegal but I am unsure of another way around this.

****I also tried adding it to a starting byte string RF_Pack = b'\x36\67\x4R' and it prints out like b'\x01!* any reason?

code used:

```
MyByte = b'\x01\x21\x2A'
streetnum= '2894'
streetnum = streetnum.encode('utf-8')
streetnumArray = [] #new list 

for i in range(0,len(streetnum ),2): #separate string every two characters 
   streetnumArray.append(streetnum [i:i+2]) #append into list 
for i in range(0,len(streetnumArray)): 
   MyByte= MyByte + b'\x' + streetnumArray[i]
```

Comment: `b'\x'` is not a valid byte literal, the key thing to grok is that `\x` is an escape sequence, you can't *concatenate* that to anything, because it doesn't actually exist in the byte string itself, it's part of *source code*. Can you provide a minimal example of exactly what you are trying to accomplish, i.e. exact input with exact expected output?

Comment: yes:               street number 2894 ----> 2894 is built for a byte string b'\x28\x94

Comment: You need to clarify what you are trying to do. A [mcve] helps, with exact inputs/expected outputs. What is `Street_Num`?

Comment: Street_num is a parse string that was then broken up and converted into bytes in a list, Street_Num[0] = 28 and Street_Num[1] = 94 as bytes

Comment: Please, again, *provide an exact example with inputs and expected outputs*. Don't make me guess,  *there is no need for ambiguity, you are working with a programming language*. What does it mean to say "28 as bytes"? EDIT: to be clear, I should be able to copy-and-paste your input and ouput into, say, a REPL and get a result

Comment: sorry I thought I was giving an example the input is the user input: street number 2894 this is then parsed to be the string 2894 which I convert into a byte string using .encode('utf-8') after separating the two digits into Street_Num[]. Street_Num[0] = 28 and Street_Num[1] = 94. The end goal is to append them to look like b'\x28\x94'

Comment: I don't know how to be any more clear: **don't use English to describe your data, use Python**. Provide *Python code* that I can copy and paste. E.g. `street_num = [b'28', b'94']`? `street_num = [28, 94]`? Please ad this to the original question, not in the comments

Comment: what is `panid_re`? did you just mean `streetnum = '2894.encode()`?

Comment: ya that was an error I fixed it

Comment: And you want `result = b'\x01\x21\x2A\x28\x94'`?

Comment: yes precisely I am new to this and I couldn't find anything on it either

Comment: So, I *think* you just want something like `MyByte + bytes([int(i, 16) for i in streetnumArray])`

Comment: The thing is, every two digits represents the hexadecimal value of the byte you want to add?

Comment: I'm not sure when I tried it I got this b'\x01!*\x08@\x08@'. I am also trying to establish this at the very beginning MyByte = b'\x01\x21\x2A' and it is resulting in this: b'\x01!* any idea why?

Comment: I just remembered that `bytes` has a convenience method for converting from hex strings, `fromhex`, so you can just do: `b'\x01\x21\x2A' + bytes.fromhex('2894')` the other approach I had should have worked, I tested it with your data, but no need to re-invent the wheel. Anyway, as to your other question, that's because `b'\x01!*' == b'\x01\x21\x2A'`, Python uses valid ascii characters in the printed representation of your bytes object for byte values in the printible ascii range.

Comment: So I don't want to deal with hexadecimal, I just want to append a string that I have parsed onto a byte string. The string is contained in an array, I hope that makes sense. Also is there a way to stop it from printing out b'\x01!*' and instead b'\x01\x21\x2A'. I know you said they were the same I'm curious.

Comment: You have to understand, what you are saying: "I just want to append a string that I have parsed onto a byte string." *doesn't describe the output you want*. Your strings represent hexadecimal byte values, and you want to append *those bytes* not the actual strings. And no, there's no way to prevent it from printing like that, outside of modifying the python interpreter, either by re-compiling it or by using some black-magic hacks to monkey-patch built-in classes. Or you could write your own function to print it as you wish.

Comment: IOW, `b'\x28'` has nothing to do with `b'28'`, aside from it being the hexadecimal representation of the byte on the left. Consider, `len(b'\x28') == 1` whereas `len(b'28') == 2`. The `'\x28'` notation is an *escape sequence* that you write in a *`bytes` literal*, i.e. it is *source code*. You *could* construct this source-code string and then eval it, but again, really, you should just use `bytes.fromhex`

Comment: ok I see what you are saying now, I have used NAME_str = '01' + '21' + '2A' then NAME = bytearray.fromhex(NAME_str). Im still getting b'\x01!*' ( == b'\x01\x21\x2A') so is there a way to keep it from printing the ascii definition?

Comment: No, there isn't. That's just how `bytes` objects are represented, you can of course, write your own helper function to create whatever printed representation you want. but note, if you have bytes, you can just do `list(NAME_str)` and it will give you a list of `int` objects representing those bytes, and if you want a hex format, you can use `list(map(hex, NAME_str))` if you want it in hex